# White screen on Laravel HasMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Not sure why Laravel is doing a loop until it's out of memory here. I'm trying to create a has many through relationship with my models, but it's just giving me a white screen. Here are my three models

Contractor.php

```
class Contractor extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'contractors';

   public function contractorTrades() {
          return $this->hasMany('ContractorTrade', 'contractor_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

ContractorTrade.php

```
class ContractorTrade extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'contractor_trades';

   public function contractor() {
          return $this->belongsTo('Contractor');
   }
}
```

Trade.php

```
class Trade extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'trades';
}
```

If I call

```
Contractor::first()->contractorTrades();
```

My app runs out of memory and crashes on a white screen with no errors. During my debugging I made it so I was only testing the hasMany before even trying the hasManyThrough and I still cant get it to work. When I run it through Artisan, it looks like it's just looping over and over.

Comment: Have you tried removing the contractor_id and id from the hasMany() call? Also can you please post the table creation SQL, I would like to reproduce this on my machine. And lastly, have you turned debugging on in your config file?

Comment: Have you messed with `newQuery` method? Or maybe a global scope or something like this? Otherwise there is no way for infinite loop with this call. Show whole code you have there.

Comment: Hey, so I figured out one issue but it didn't solve my ultimate problem.

For some reason if I called ->contractorTrades(); in the view instead of ->contractorTrades; I had the whitescreen issue.

My issue continues though with the relationship not working correctly. When I call $contractor->trades, the following SQL is occuring

    select `trades`.*, `contractor_trades`.`contractor_id` from `trades` inner join `contractor_trades` on `contractor_trades`.`id` = `trades`.`id` where `contractor_trades`.`contractor_id` = ? [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [time] => 1.53 )

Comment: The above sql should be select `trades`.*, `contractor_trades`.`contractor_id` from `trades` inner join `contractor_trades` on `contractor_trades`.`trade_id` = `trades`.`id` where `contractor_trades`.`contractor_id` = ? [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [time] => 1.53 )

Comment: My 3 tables are: contractors {id, metadata}, contractor_trades {id, contractor_id, trade_id}, trades {id, metadata}

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. This might be useful for someone who comes from a Rails background like I do. The perspective of how I was looking at was wrong.

I restructured how my databases was supposed to look like and followed the instructions on the laravel website for the belongsToMany function. I have it working correctly now and it is performing the correct inner join statement.